# How to get screenshot from RemoteWebDriver server instead of local FirefoxDriver?

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I am running Selenium WebDriver test on a remote PC from my laptop(java client), by using RemoteWebDriver.  But RemoteWebDriver haven't provided screenshot API to directly get a screenshot of remote PC.  Googled a lot but found seems need use to Json API to get it from remoteWebDriver server directly.  Anyone can give me some instruction about how to do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `RemoteWebDriver` must be augmented before you can use the screenshot capability. As you have no doubt already found, attempting to cast without augmenting results in an exception.

```
WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver( ... );
driver           = new Augmenter().augment( driver );
( (TakesScreenshot)driver ).getScreenshotAs( ... );
```

---

Comment: Can you please tell us why the screenshot capability was not built into the RemoteWebDriver ? I wonder what this extra step does in the background. BTW, per the docs, Augmenter is an experimental feature and must be used with caution.

Answer (score 5):

I was able to get this working...here is what you need to do:

1) Create a new class file in a Util directory or somewhere

```
package com.util;

import java.net.URL;
import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType;
import org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DriverCommand;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;

public class ScreenShotRemoteWebDriver extends RemoteWebDriver implements TakesScreenshot {

    public ScreenShotRemoteWebDriver(URL url, DesiredCapabilities dc) {

        super(url, dc);

    }

    @Override
    public <X> X getScreenshotAs(OutputType<X> target) throws WebDriverException {

        if ((Boolean) getCapabilities().getCapability(CapabilityType.TAKES_SCREENSHOT)) {
            return target.convertFromBase64Png(execute(DriverCommand.SCREENSHOT).getValue().toString());
        }
        return null;

    }

}
```

2) Then...where ever you start the RemoteWeDriver, replace with this code:

```
driver = new ScreenShotRemoteWebDriver(new URL(-PUT YOUR HUB URL HERE-),cap);
```

Your screenshots will be stored locally.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is the best way:

```
public<T> Object getScreenshotAs(OutputType<T> outputType) {
    Augmenter augmenter = new Augmenter(); 
    TakesScreenshot ts = (TakesScreenshot) augmenter.augment(driver);
    return ts.getScreenshotAs(outputType);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution:
https://groups.google.com/d/topic/selenium-users/NLHXlhPrADs/discussion

Answer (score 0):

The RemoteWebDriver does not implement the TakesScreenShot and the methods described here to cast the instance of RemoteWebDriver to TakesScreenShot will cause a ClassCastException. I'll see if I can find a solution as I'm interested in doing the same.

The Augmenter will "enhance the interfaces implemented by this instance of WebDriver iff that instance is a RemoteWebDriver". Depending on how the RemoteWebDriver is configured and how the selenium server is running on the remote host, it may be possible to get a screen shot in using the org.openqa.selenium.remote.Augmenter.

I've configured the RemoteWebDriver to use DesiredCapabilities.htmlUnit() capabilities and this gives an ClassCastError. If the RemoteWebDriver is configured with the capabilities of a driver that implements the TakesScreenshot interface, then a ClassCastException may not occur, though I have yet to test this.

From the TakesScreenshot interface, the known implementing drivers are: AndroidDriver, AndroidWebDriver, ChromeDriver, EventFiringWebDriver, FirefoxDriver, InternetExplorerDriver, IPhoneDriver, IPhoneSimulatorDriver, and SafariDriver

Comment: I've run this using a Firefox driver on the server and it does work!