# Capture Test Video on Remote Machine in JUnit/Selenium Tests

Tags: video, junit4, selenium-grid

I am running Selenium Web Driver Scripts using Eclipse3.2-Junit4 Framework and Selenium Grid on remote machines. I want to capture screen video where the tests are running. I tried Monte Media Library but it records video only on Host machine i.e. Hub. But my requirement is to record complete test running on Selenium Node (i.e. remote machine).
Could you please advise if there is some Java Library for this thing.

Thanks !!!

Comment: Check this answer for a similar scenario, where a grid is used http://stackoverflow.com/a/17168283/654026

Answer (score 1):

I thought of that for a long time but technically it's almost useless to have a video.

Screenshots can replace a video quite good.

From my point of view [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6598227/1300626) is the way to go.

Further questions?

Comment: I think, it is infact very useful to have video. If we have test video, then after test completion, one can see what happened during the test.

Comment: that's also possible with screenshots... I don't see the large gap in evaluation... you can even manage to clock the page loading phasis...

Answer (score 0):

You can use VNC viewer or Remote Desktop connection to the remote machine and the Monte Video recorder would record everything on the local machine's screen--including the output from the viewer.